# iOS 7 - Using MLPAutoCompleteTextField with a plain NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete

I am relatively new to iOS Development and I wanted to implement an autocomplete textfield in my application. Upon doing research, I have come across [this library](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField), MLPAutoCompleteTextField. I downloaded it, ran the Demo, and tried to understand how it works.

From what I got, the demo uses a custom class for the Array and a custom cell view that's why the autocomplete in the demo contains the flag of the country.

However, what I want to implement is a much simpler version, one that would only use an Array, no more custom classes for the data and the cell layout.

Here is what I have so far:

My FirstViewController.h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
#import "MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDataSource.h"
#import "MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDelegate.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDataSource, MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *groupID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *part;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *brand;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *barcode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *itemName;

@property (weak) IBOutlet MLPAutoCompleteTextField *groupIDInput;
@property (weak) IBOutlet MLPAutoCompleteTextField *partInput;
@property (weak) IBOutlet MLPAutoCompleteTextField *brandInput;
@property (weak) IBOutlet MLPAutoCompleteTextField *barcodeInput;
@property (weak) IBOutlet MLPAutoCompleteTextField *itemNameInput;

@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;

@property (assign) BOOL testWithAutoCompleteObjectsInsteadOfStrings;

@end
```

As you can see, I have 5 AutoCompleteTextViews and I intend to use the 5 Arrays to supply the data for the autoCompleteTextViews.

This is my FirstViewController.m File:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
#import "MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDataSource.h"
#import "MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDelegate.h"
#import "MLPAutoCompleteTextField.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize groupID;
@synthesize part;
@synthesize brand;
@synthesize barcode;
@synthesize itemName;

@synthesize groupIDInput;
@synthesize partInput;
@synthesize brandInput;
@synthesize barcodeInput;
@synthesize itemNameInput;

@synthesize searchButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self setType];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - MLPAutoCompleteTextField DataSource

- (void)groupIDInput:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
 possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string
        completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSArray *completions;
        if(self.testWithAutoCompleteObjectsInsteadOfStrings){
           completions = [self allCountryObjects];
        } else {
          completions = [self allCountries];
        }

        handler(completions);
    });
}


-(void) setType{
   [self.groupIDInput setAutoCompleteTableAppearsAsKeyboardAccessory:NO];
}


- (NSArray *)allCountryObjects{
  if(!self.groupID){
      NSArray *countryNames = [self allCountries];
      NSMutableArray *mutableCountries = [NSMutableArray new];
      for(NSString *countryName in countryNames){
          [mutableCountries addObject:countryName];
      }

      [self setGroupID:[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableCountries]];
  }

  return self.groupID;
}

- (NSArray *)allCountries{
    NSArray *countries =
   @[/* Insert Long List of Countries Here */];

   return countries;
}

@end
```

However, my problem now is that in the demo, there is a line that goes `[self.autocompleteTextField registerAutoCompleteCellClass:[DEMOCustomAutoCompleteCell class]` wherein the custom cell class is used. I get the feeling that I'm also supposed to create my own custom cell class even though I'm not implementing anything fancy.

So, question is:

Do I have to implement my own CustomAutoCompleteObject and CustomAutoCompleteCell? If not, how can I implement this library just by using simple Arrays?

Any help is appreciated. I have been working on this for the past 4-5 hours and my lack of iOS Dev knowledge is taking it's toll on me.

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to use a predeclared array instead of a mutable one populated by a database query, I also made some changes as follows:

```
- (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
 possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string
            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSArray *completions;
        //completions = [self allCountries];
        completions = [self initializeGroupIDArray];

        handler(completions);
    });
}
```

This function is attached to the storyboard.

And my initializeGroupIDArray is as follows:

```
-(NSArray *)initializeGroupIDArray{
    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"itemList.db"];

    NSMutableArray *groupArray =    @[/* Insert List of Countries Here */];


    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];

    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID FROM ItemList";

    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];

    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *queryResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"GROUPID"]];

        // loading your data into the array, dictionaries.
        NSLog(@"GroupID = %@", queryResult);
        [groupArray addObject:queryResult];
    }
    [database close];

    NSArray *groupID;
    [groupID = groupArray copy];
    return groupID;

}
```

However, it seems to me that I am not adding my results from the database query properly. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't initialize my mutable array. Now goes goes as such:

```
#pragma mark - MLPAutoCompleteTextField DataSource

- (void)autoCompleteTextField:(MLPAutoCompleteTextField *)textField
 possibleCompletionsForString:(NSString *)string
            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))handler{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSLog(@"autoCompleteTextField Entered");

        NSArray *completions;
        completions = [self allGroups];

        handler(completions);
    });
}
```

allGroups function:

```
-(NSArray *)allGroups{

    NSLog(@"allGroups Entered");

    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"itemList.db"];

    NSMutableArray *groupArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //This bad body right here.

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];

    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID FROM ItemList";

    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];

    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *groupIDName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"GROUPID"]];

        // loading your data into the array, dictionaries.
        NSLog(@"Group ID = %@", groupIDName);
        [groupArray addObject:groupIDName];
    }
    [database close];


    NSLog(@"size of groupArray (mutbale): %d", [groupArray count]);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [groupArray count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"Group Array (mutable) :%@", groupArray[i]);
    }

    NSArray *groupID;
    [groupID = groupArray copy];

    NSLog(@"size of groupID (immutbale): %d", [groupID count]);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [groupID count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"Group ID (non mutable) :%@", groupID[i]);
    }

    NSLog(@"allGroups before return statement");
    return groupID;

}
```